# Почему после запроса curl страница перезагружается?

Tags: php, php-curl

Отправляю на сервер запрос при помощи `curl`:

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
    "Content-Type: application/json"
]);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo($response);
```

Вот после этого `echo($response);` страница, с которой вызывается запрос, перенаправляется на другой адрес (явно взятый с сервера, к которому делается запрос).

В чем может быть причина?

Comment: Возможно, что в респонсе есть какой-то js-код, который после echo в браузере выполняется и происходит редирект.

Comment: @Alex, да, видимо, так и есть, спасибо.

Comment: Потому что вы используете [CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.curl-setopt.php)

Comment: @DanielProtopopov нет, без нее то же самое.

Answer (score 0):

> Возможно, что в респонсе есть какой-то js-код, который после echo в браузере выполняется и происходит редирект

Запишите содержимое респонсе в файл и посмотри почему происходит редирект

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант используйте функцию htmlentities()

```
echo htmlentities($response);
```